# when entering data in the search column in datagridview gets lag

Tags: winforms, datagridview, c#-3.0

The problem that I am facing is related to the performance and usability of the `dataGridView2` control in my application. There is a lag when entering data in the "Items" column of `dataGridView2`, especially after adding more rows.

```
 private void textBox3_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cntObject.Text) && dataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name == "Items")
            {
                panel2.Visible = true;
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                var item_name = cntObject.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [item_id],[item_name],[item_brand],[item_catergory],[item_country],[item_selling_price],[item_net_price],[item_discounnt],[qty],[supplier_name] FROM [dbo].[items] where item_name like '%" + item_name + "%' ";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                int count = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("COUNT(item_id)", ""));
                label13.Text = count.ToString();

                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                con.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }


        }
```

Can't I boost up this process.